# How to use JsonIgnore when retrieving data from data base but not when registering or logging in, in ASP.NET Core (C#)

Tags: c#

To prevent showing password when retrieving user from data base I use JsonIgnore atribute and it works fine for logged user, but it prevents registering a new user or logging in another user. How to use JsonIgnore to work when retrieving data from data base but not when registering or logging in, in `ASP.NET Core (C#)`?

This is my user model:

```
   public class UserModel
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar (30)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar (100)")]
        
        [JsonIgnore]       
        public string Password { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: Why would your database class use a [JsonIgnore] attribute? Are you using the same classes for your database and your REST API?

Comment: Don' t use JsonIgnore. Just assign password = null  before sending  when you don' t need it.

Comment: That's not what `JsonIgnore` does. In fact, there's absolutely no reason to even have a `Password` property in a `User` object. Passwords are never stored in clear text, they're salted and hashed at least 1000 times. Authentication code never needs to know even that value, it only needs to hash the user's input and compare it with the stored value. There's no reason to retrieve the password hash from the database

Comment: Also, I hope "Password" is short for PasswordHash, right?

Comment: Why are you creating your own `User` and authentication instead of using the built-in ASP.NET Core Identity? It already handles secure password storage, comparison, change etc. All ASP.NET versions going back to 2002 included secure authentication and user storage

Comment: Sorry for the question, as nvoigt pointed out rightly, I made mistake by using the same model for database and REST API.

Comment: No problem, I hope my answer helps you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Never retrieve the password from database, even when you are checking it. You should "search" for a user with that password and retrieve an Id or other data if exists. You never should do that.

Suggestion:

Even more, you should have your password encrypted in one way with `SHA-256` or `SHA-512` and stored in another table that doesn't call "passwords" or related field to that. Also never do a "`select *`" even as "select all fields" if you won't use them in that business logic. Less is more.

Comment: Simply hashing is meaningless. At the very least, the password needs to be salted and hashed multiple times (ASP.NET Core's default is at least 1000 times) to ensure it can't be reverse-engineered. Otherwise one could calculate SHA512 hashes on the fly and compare them to the stored hashes until a match is found

Comment: .NET uses the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-6.0) to salt and hash at least 1000 times using HMACSHA1, an algorithm designed to hash keys. The algorithm can change with HMACSHA256 and -512 available out of the box.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand. Is a sample observation and suggestion for someone that is novice and is learning. For sure I don't have the expertise for explain that to a novice. and there is no space enough in this answer to explain everything.

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment then

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I respect your opinion but I don't share it. The suggestion was only the part about the encription. The answer is another part. I will separate them. Thanks.